Error : ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'
i am trying to train my model fo object detection using tensorflow when i execute the command python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py i get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' even that i have the model_lib_v2 under object_detection\research why ? i am using tensorflow 2.x and python 3.x
